# GOPATH in Hyperledger Fabric

Tags: installation, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, prerequisites, gopath

I'm going through the Hyperledger Fabric documentation at

https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.2/prereqs.html

and I've noticed that in the section "Getting Started" you start of 
with the prerequisites. So basically, installing all the dependencies for using fabric.

However, Fabric is not installed in the prerequisites section, but yet, in the Go Programming Language-part of that same section, it is mentioned that

> First, you must set the environment variable GOPATH to point at the Go workspace containing the downloaded Fabric code base, with something like:

But there is no downloaded Fabric code base at that point.

What am I supposed to do? What is the value of GOPATH supposed to be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of this step, there is no fabric code base install or downloaded. It is a folder structure recommendation. In the very next step, you will be guided to download the fabric binaries, sample, and docker images. I would suggest you to jump [here](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.2/build_network.html) for quick setup of the fabric.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification!